# Not able to connect to Oracle Database using JDBC Driver in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbc, spring-boot

I have written the url, username etc of the database in application.properties file. I have also defined `@Autowired` annotation in the controller for JdbcTemplate. But now when I execute, I get this error-

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

> Field jdbc in com.sab.Controller required a bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate' that could not be found.
>       - Bean method 'jdbcTemplate' not loaded because @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans

Action:

Consider revisiting the conditions above or defining a bean of type `org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate` in your configuration.

Can anyone help me to resolve this error.

Comment: post the configuration as well as make sure you have the right dependencies. also look [here](https://springframework.guru/configuring-spring-boot-for-oracle/)

Comment: The error message gives you a suggestion of what you need to do. Did you try that? Spring Boot does not automatically create a `JdbcTemplate` bean for you, you need to do that yourself. Add a method to your Spring Boot application class with a `@Bean` annotation on it that returns a `JdbcTemplate`.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I have checked the dependencies, nothing is missing.

Comment: @Jesper thank you for the idea. Since i am new to Spring boot and I dont know how to do that can you please give me some example that creates the Bean jdbctemplate method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a Spring bean of type `JdbcTemplate`. You can do that by adding a `@Bean` method to your Spring Boot application class that creates and returns a `JdbcTemplate`. For example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ExampleApplication {

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ExampleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Also, if you haven't already done so, you have to add the properties for the database connection to the file `src/main/resources/application.properties`. Spring Boot uses these to create the `DataSource` bean. For example (you need to put the appropriate values in here; this is an example for using an H2 in-memory database):

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:demo
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
```

Finally, you need to make sure that you have a dependency on the appropriate database driver in your `pom.xml`. For example (for the H2 database), you need to have this in the `dependencies` section of `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```